# Redirecting to index.mtc

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a home page called index.mtc.. And a registration page called registration.mtc. The .mtc is a special file type that was created. We can write php, jsp, java, jquery, html all in the same file.

The index.mtc has some logic in it that needs to be executed inorder for the site to work properly.

So lets say the url is `http://www.testwebsite.com`

and the registration url is: So lets say the url is `http://www.testwebsite.com/registration.mtc`

When a user just immediately navigates to So lets say the url is `http://www.testwebsite.com/registration.mtc` the logic in `index.mtc` gets bypassed and is not executed and causes problems.

So question now..

Is there a way for me to redirect them to the `index.mtc` page if they ever go to the `registration.mtc` link directly? So the code has to check and see if the `index.mtc` webpage was hit first, if it was not hit then it should redirect to `index.mtc`. But, if the `index.mtc` site was already hit then it should just continue and not redirect back to `index.mtc`.

Comment: Isn't this already asked here [Redirecting back to index page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166430/redirecting-back-to-index-page)?

Comment: Oh weird... Really weird.. I knew I created another one, but I couldnt find it. It was as if it just disappeared.. Anyway thanks for the link. I will check it out.